# At what point can I use the generated HTML?

Tags: angular

Imaging a template like this:

```
<a id="registerLink" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" #registercontainer>Login</a>
```

and the underlying component as:

```
@ViewChild('registercontainer')
registercontainer: ElementRef;

...

this.loginService.checkLogin().then((result: boolean) => {
    isLoggedIn = result;
    if(!result) {
         --> HERE
         this.doSomethingWithTheATag(this.registercontainer);
    }
}.catch(error: any) {}
```

Question is, since because of ngIf, the component may or may not be rendered, at what point can I use the view? Can I reliably always use it right after the `*ngIf` condition becomes true?

Similarly, if I'm using `jquery`, can I immediately after setting the variable that should render the html use the value?

For instance, in my `doSomethingWith(...)` can I call `$('#registerLink').xyz()`?

If not, how can I know when the element is rendered?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook:

```
import {AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // your ViewChild can be accessed
}
```

If you change the variable that is connected `*ngIf`, you have to wait for a cycle until you can call operations on the ViewChild (until it is in the DOM).

The simplest way to do this is to put the rest of your logic in a setTimeout.

```
this.loginService.checkLogin().then((result: boolean) => {
    isLoggedIn = result;
    if(!result) {
         setTimeout(() => {
             this.doSomethingWithTheATag(this.registercontainer);
         });
    }
}.catch(error: any) {}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've been doing but I don't really like the `setTimeout()`. It's very hacky and not intuitive at all.

Comment: I agree. You could also try out to trigger change detection manually, you will find articles on Google and Stackoverflow on that topic.